# Memory leak tracing with AppVerifier

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a C++ application that has some minimal leaks, and I would like to fix them. I am using AppVerifier to dump the leaked objects, and I can get the addresses and first few bytes of the allocated memory.

Unfortunately, those first bytes and raw address is not enough to pinpoint the allocation stack trace, is there a method to get complete allocation data dump, and find the stack that's allocating the memory?

I could put _`CrtSetBreakAlloc` via the leak number, but unfortunatelly it's a threaded application and those numbers float up and down.

Does anyone have a suggestion what I could try?

Comment: Is there a pattern in the allocation numbers? I mean can you identify some predicate like "the distance between the first one and the second one is always 514"?

Comment: Yes, there is, hmmm, looking at it, seems it could be a class, instances of which are leaked multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the gflags utility you can enable storing call stack information (gflags +ust).  However, your applications will now run slower and take more memory.

Side-remark: To be honest, I never got all those Microsoft utilities (leak-tracing in the C-RunTime, Gflags, UMDH, AppVerifier, LeakDiag) to do exactly what I wanted.  In the end, I simply wrote my own memory allocator in which I can add whatever tracing I want (call stack, red zone marking, delayed freeing, consistency checking, ...).

Comment: How do you call it? From windbg during the first break (on open executable)?

Comment: You have to call GFLAGS before starting your application.  Be sure to explicitly only do this for your executable otherwise your whole system will be terribly slow. (gflags is part of the Microsoft Debugging Tools for Windows)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using UMDH to track memory leaks. You first have  to use GFlags to turn on storing call stack tracing whenever memory is allocated. The docs on UMDH state how to use it.

But recently I've finally tried out visual leak detector, and it works fabulous on my monstrous, big app.
http://vld.codeplex.com